# Regex dispatching to various jetty handlers

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

Is there way to to use context handlers but also have a handle that doesn't catch all files that would normally be 404s?  I'm making a HandlerList of ContextHandlers that map a url to a handler, but everything not caught seem to go to the last handler, which represents the homepage and shouldn't have anything after its slash.  I want requests to localhost without anything on the path to go to that handler and not requests like http://example.com/some_file_that_does_not_exist_and_should_return_a_404.jpg, which currently goes to the Home handler.

```
    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] {
            Utils.createContextHandler(resourceHandler, "/static"),
            Utils.createContextHandler(new Step1(), "/step1"),
            Utils.createContextHandler(new Step2(), "/step2"),
            Utils.createContextHandler(new Home(), "/") // <-- all 404s are going here
    });
    server.setHandler(handlers);
```

Is there not a way to set it by regex?  For example, what if I were doing something like tinyurl, where I wanted a dynamic hash tag or number of some type sent to a specific handler?  Could I send check if five digits exist, send to handler A and if it's six digits send to handler B?  Or should I just create my own handler list that uses regexes?  Or should I just put logic into my Home handler to catch weird files?

I'm used to a url dispatching configuration like django's.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/